# SwiftUI Parent / Child leaking

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, memory-leaks

Recently I saw an issue in SwiftUI and broke it down to this code for demonstration purposes:

```
import SwiftUI

// Parent view
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var overlayVisible: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show") {
                withAnimation {
                    overlayVisible = true
                }
            }

            .overlay {
                if overlayVisible {
                    ChildView(onHide: {
                        withAnimation {
                            overlayVisible = false
                        }
                    })
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// Child view + @StateObject
class ChildViewStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var alertVisible: Bool = false
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @StateObject var store: ChildViewStore = ChildViewStore()
    
    var onHide: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.gray
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all) // Ignore just for the color
            .overlay{
                VStack {
                    Button("Dismiss") {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        onHide?()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

First I press the button "Show" and after that "Dismiss" and repeat the process a few times.
When I see "Show" again I press the memory inspector in XCode.
I see that an instance of ChildViewStore leaked in memory.

[image: leak]

Is this expected behavior or a SwiftUI bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce with the given code. Are you missing something?

Comment: I can reproduce it every time. Using an iPhone XR as real testing device. After repeating the "Show" -> "Dismiss" procedure I press Debug Memory Graph and have one instance of ChildViewStore in memory. I edited the question - see image with "LeakTest (1)"

Comment: So weird, it still works. Tested on both XCode 14.3 and 15.0.1, iOS 15.2.

Comment: Using Xcode 15.1, iPhone XR with iOS 17.2.1 (latest update as of today 21.12.23)

Comment: Try fixing your conditional overlay, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71983352/259521 my guess is the issue is because you didn't read `overlayVisible` anywhere in ContentView's body so this would fix that.

Comment: Can you get it to "leak" more than one instance?

Comment: Yes! This is an extracted portion of a much larger app where I can get even the instances of overlay to be ramped up (every opening of overlay = one additional instance in memory leaked)

Comment: @malhal Tried your suggestion, it did not work. Still there is at least one instance of ChildViewStore in memory